# How to use opcache_reset function?

Tags: php, apc, opcache

I have some troubles using the opcache_reset function.
I'm working on a Symfony 2 project. I have to use this function, so I created a route who applies this function then it redirect me to the homepage.

But my function want to call the opcache_reset function from my namespace, is there a way to tell that the opcache_reset function is "native" and call the right function?

Here is my error :

```
 Attempted to call function "opcache_reset" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller".
```

And here is my function :

```
public function resetOpcacheAction(Request $request) {
    try{
        opcache_reset()

    } catch(\Exception $e){

    }
    return $this->redirect('homepage');
}
```

Comment: Call it like `\opcache_reset()`.

Comment: Thanks Daan, but it shows me another error now : "Attempted to call function "opcache_reset" from the global namespace". I tryed to add "use function opcache_reset", it doesn't works too. PHPStorm recommand me to add "ext-zend-opcache" to my composer.json. I think it shouldn't tell me this because OPCache is native, isn't it ?

Comment: It is not native check out the [install instructions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php)

Comment: Are you sure that you've enabled the OpCache extension? Afterwards, there is no need to use the backslash in front of the method call

Comment: Okay, my error was that I missed to uncomment a line from my php.ini... It works now thanks ! Another question throught, what are the differences between make a full restart of services including PHP, or call the opcache_reset function after putting in production ? Is it similar ? Thanks you!

Answer (score -4):

This function resets the entire opcode cache. After calling opcache_reset(), all scripts will be reloaded and reparsed the next time they are hit.

What is opchache ?

OpCache – which stores precompiled script bytecode in the memory.
As each PHP script is being compiled at runtime, a part of the execution time gets used for transforming the human readable code into code that can be understood by the machine. A bytecode cache engine like OpCache, APC or Xcache does it only once – during the first execution of a specific PHP file. 
   Then the precompiled script is being stored in memory, which should lead to performance boosts in our PHP applications.

Use like this:-

```
opcache_reset();
```

Reference link:- https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/opcache_reset/php-opcache_reset-function-examples.html

Comment: And how does this relate to the given error message?